# How to format numerical values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to format pandas dataframe results in float. The code below displays values in scientific notations. Any ides how to rectify would be helpful.

The code that generates the output:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/new/"
page = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=1)
pagedata = page.text
usecols = ["Name", "Price", "1h", "24h", "MarketCap", "Volume"]#, "Blockchain"]


df = pd.read_html(pagedata)[0] #Checking table
df[["Name", "Symbol"]] = df["Name"].str.split(r"\d+", expand=True)
df = df.rename(columns={"Fully Diluted Market Cap": "MarketCap"})[usecols]

numcols = df.columns[df.columns != 'Name']
df[numcols] = df[numcols].apply(lambda c:pd.to_numeric(c.str.replace(r'[^\d.]|(?<!\d)\.|\.(?!\d)', '', regex=True)))
df = df.sort_values('24h', ascending=False)

print (df)
```

Current Output:

```
               Name         Price     1h     24h     MarketCap    Volume
0        DollarPepe  4.402000e-02  16.87  597.88  4.000000e+00    541219
12    Perry The BNB  5.442000e-08   2.90  519.49  1.144662e+07  25606468
2              JEFF  1.802000e-01   3.66  202.07  1.802032e+07  21195038
19              KEK  5.665000e-08  57.52  154.52  4.405980e+06   5925829
16        FlokiPepe  2.836000e-09  34.48  118.71  1.193154e+06   1394199
1       Billy Token  3.168000e-05  11.69   72.83  2.198928e+06   5389786
```

Needed Output:

```
               Name  Price         1h      24h        MarketCap        Volume
0        DollarPepe  $0.04     $17.72%  16.87%           $586.08         $4.0     
12    Perry The BNB  $0.00      $2.66%   $557%    $12,086,284.00  $25,525,925
2              JEFF  $0.18      $1.91%   $194%    $17,541,936.00  $21,178,793
19              KEK  $0.00     $57.80%   $221%     $5,560,854.00   $5,864,987
16        FlokiPepe  $0.00     $22.75%   $110%     $1,132,337.00   $1,382,867
1       Billy Token  $0.00     $14.31%    $72%     $2,235,948.00   $5,405,861
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `display.float_format` to affect the display of the `Volume` column as that has an `int64` data type. You could use the [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) method, supplying a list of formatters for each column type:

```py
formats = {
    'Price': '${:.2f}'.format,
    '1h': '{:.2f}%'.format,
    '24h': '{:.2f}%'.format,
    'MarketCap': '${:,.2f}'.format,
    'Volume': '{:,d}'.format
}
print(df.to_string(formatters=formats))
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
             Name Price     1h     24h      MarketCap     Volume
0      DollarPepe $0.04 16.87% 597.88%          $4.00    541,219
12  Perry The BNB $0.00  2.90% 519.49% $11,446,620.00 25,606,468
2            JEFF $0.18  3.66% 202.07% $18,020,320.00 21,195,038
19            KEK $0.00 57.52% 154.52%  $4,405,980.00  5,925,829
16      FlokiPepe $0.00 34.48% 118.71%  $1,193,154.00  1,394,199
1     Billy Token $0.00 11.69%  72.83%  $2,198,928.00  5,389,786
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this line. This ensures that the global formatting for float is of 2 decimal places.

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2f}'.format)
```

Comment: I tried that one but the last column is not affected. Any ideas?

Comment: last column might be string type.

Comment: Agreed, this is more of a one size fit all answer. @Nick has given a more comprehensive answer that should fit your exact requirements